# vb.net compare two table, insert the result into new table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, compare

I have two identical table which consist of 3 field: ID, TID, and ITEM..
ID acts as primary key, TID identifies group of ITEM. Each TID could have different number of ITEM.

i want to compare the 2 identical table with condition like

1. check each grouped ITEM by TID in table 1 to each grouped ITEM by TID in table2

   if table1. grouped Item exist as much as N in table2, it will be inserted into new table by query `INSERT SELECT`

   for example at the screenshot, `C - F -A` has 3 occurences in table 2, thus they will be inserted into new table..

could it be done using mysql query?

i've already tried this using program by populating the two table into two 2d array, comparing them and with simple `IF CLAUSE`, getting the desired results.. and it worked well..

but the problem is, when i'm using huge database, it take ridiculous time to complete..

when i'm comparing 1st 2d array(table1 with 2k records) and 2nd array (table2 with 870 records), it take 2 hours to complete!!

this is the actual database

[image]

and this one is what i've already tried, populating two table above into 2d array.. while assigning both 2d arrays with table records, i also include the `IF CLAUSE` to check if element of 1st 2d array has N occurences in 2nd 2d arrays, the `INSERT SELECT` query will be executed..

[image]

**the yellow blocked node col** in 1st 2d array above, will e inserted into new table because it has 3 occurences in 2nd 2d array,

the number 3 came from user input

but since i'm using database object anyway, it cost me an expensive performance and time, too, i'm using **vb.net 2005**

i believe that there are alternative method for this problem.. could you all please tell me how the method? using mysql query or other method that could perform faster than one that i've tried?

best regards from me, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

use linq its does all the mysql quires.  You can find great documentation on it on msdn.  Just build the db with mysql sever and use linq or entity they will both do all the commands for you.  That way you can do data binding and save that info and pull it or whatever if you have more quesiton I have a copy of code in c# that uses tables for contact info I can see to you

This is a link to GitHub that contains the C# version using Linq
https://github.com/psychotiic/WebContactAppUsingLinq.cs

Comment: thx for the answer sir.  i forget to mention, but i'm not good with linq, since it's new to me and even now i'm using vs 2005. so could you please suggest me another solution beside LINQ, please? thx u

Answer (score 0):

you will be able to use linq with that code that I just provided even though its C# its will be easy to figure out and if not you can find plenty of C# - VB code changers on the web for free.

Comment: i really appreciated your answer bro, include the code to.. but i'm still using vb 2005 which is not suppported for LINQ.. and to be upgraded into higher version of vs is a much work for me because my project solution is already big. i'm afraid upgrading the vs will make all code i've made so far getting an error..

Comment: so then make a copy of the code and then upgrade it, and Im sure your going to get an error or two because there are way better ways and most likly new libraries to do things without all of that code your already useing,.  Im sure you would be able to condense the project size dramactially by using .net 4.0 or 4.5